# Почему не нужна запятая после "все же"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Все же(,) семья настояла, чтобы я подала документы...*

Почему запятая после *все же* не ставится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_115) говорит о том, что при интонационно-логическом подчеркивании запятая всё-таки может ставиться. Однако на практике я не встречаю обособленных вариантов.

Comment: Вот такой вариант: "Всё же, неужели нельзя что-нибудь сделать?" Нужно после частицы поставить несовместимое с ней слово.

Comment: Думаю, здесь не столько следующее слово влияет на интонацию и знак, сколько форма вопроса. "Всё же" может относиться либо к содержанию вопроса, либо к подразумеваемому "(всё же) ответьте," - как в вашем примере. "Всё же, семья настояла, чтобы вы подали документы, или нет?" - здесь настаивают на прямом ответе и хотят узнать о факте. Другой вариант постановки вопроса (требуется только подтверждение догадки): "и всё же (несмотря на что-то) семья настояла, чтобы вы подали документы?"

Comment: Это тема  вопросительно-восклицательных слов, которые всегда обособляются, но их надо отличать от парных вариантов, например: И что же, ты ему ответишь? - И что же ты ему ответишь?  Обычно вопросительные  сочетания стараются распространить союзами: и всё же, но всё же.  Что касается заданного вопроса, то там предложение утвердительное, а в таких предложениях "всё же" является необособленной частицей. Интересно, эта разница была указана в ответе Грамоты.ру? А то следует задать следующий вопрос: а когда требуется интонационно-логическое подчеркивание?

Answer (score 4):

Всё же, всё-таки - это частицы, которые не обособляются.

Эти частицы имеют значение уступки, поэтому похожи на вводные слова. Сходное значение имеет частица ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ, которую в начале предложения также не рекомендуется обособлять (хотя варианты с обособлением встречаются).

Почему не обособляется частица ВСЁ ЖЕ? Я думаю, вследствие  краткости  ее сложно выделить голосом в качестве самостоятельной единицы.